# Social media buttons bringing site to a halt?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins, latency

I've been developing a Wordpress theme that is optimized for mobile and it loads very fast on the sites i've been testing on. These sites get a 10K+ visitors a day so their not small sites but they are on a great server setup(s3, multiple dedicated servers & load balanced).

We activated the theme on another site that has an average of 600 users pinging the site at a time. In addition they only has a single dedicated server and no load balancing. When we activated the theme, the site came to a screeching halt. This same issue occurred on two other sites both with the similar traffic volume and hosting.

After doing some latency testing on the theme I noticing that the social media buttons are taking 7-9 seconds on average to load. This is the only thing that stuck out to me as a possible cause for the issue.

Has anyone seen these types of issues relating to Facebook's Like button or the Tweet buttons?

Comment: Just asking the blue, a song on the lips. Yay! - It's only on servers that are just crap I can tell you. If you check the server you will see that it is crap.

Comment: Yeah buttons usually slow down sites a lot. You can place placeholder images and only load the buttons when the user hovers over them.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? Your widgets broke the internets!